# US to Australia

Tags: transformer, conversion

I know nothing about electronics... I need help to figure out if I can use a power adapter that I have on hand for my overseas trip.

I have a Model PA-130 transformer for my Yamaha mixer. It's rated

AC input 110v 60Hz 
AC Output 12v 1.0A

I am going to Australia. Will I destroy my mixer in a cloud of fire and smoke if I use the following transformer?

Model WA 24c12N
AC input 100-240Vac 50-60Hz
DC output 12v 2A

If this is not going to work where would I go to purchase a transformer that will work in Australia? I'm in Nashville.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

Answer (score 1):

The potential replacement is a DC output at 12V. The original is an AC output at 12V. That could be a big difference but it's unlikely to destroy your mixer but it may not work on the DC supply or it may work with distortion on the audio signals.

Reason: An AC output of 12V has a peak voltage that is 1.414 times higher at about 17 V peak. The yamaha mixer will likely rectify that AC voltage to produce a DC level more or less based on the peak voltage of 17 V DC. If you then fed 12V DC into the mixer you are not supplying enough voltage and you may hit problems.

The best place to purchase a power supply that works is Australia. Getting 12V AC from whatever the aussie voltage is will be commonplace.

Comment: Exactly. Go to any Jaycar store in Australia. Make sure you get a converter of the correct 1A *rating.*

Comment: Could it also be that the AC signal is being double-rectified to make a dual supply?

Answer (score 0):

It looks okay to me, provided you verify the polarity. The [PA-130](http://usa.yamaha.com/products/musical-instruments/keyboards/accessories/ac-adaptors/pa-130/) appears to be a very similar 12VDC SMPS adapter, but limited to 120V in.

Don't forget to verify the polarity- most adapters these days have the center pin positive, but there are exceptions. This [Amazon.uk seller](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Yamaha-PA-130-compatible-120-240v-charger/dp/B00KW21KZU/ref=pd_sxp_f_pt) claims their adapter is PA-130 compatible, and it's positive center, but the images are too blurry to tell on the Yamaha website.

I would be more confident if your WA 24c12N is an actual Seagate supply and not some dubious thing. There is some awful garbage being sold online these days- dangerous too. You can try it on 120V before you go, of course.